# Counting the frequency of alphabet letters in a String

Tags: java, arrays

After counting the frequency of letters that appear in a particular string, I am trying to store these values in an `int` array. The array has 26 values in total for the whole alphabet. The int variable `frequency` is used as counter to capture the frequency of each letter in the string, but the count is miscalculated. What am I doing wrong?

```
int frequency = 0;
char character;
alphaCounts = new int[26];

for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {
    frequency = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < stringInput.length(); j++) {
        character = stringInput.charAt(j);
        if (character == alphabet[i]) {
            frequency++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(alphabet[i] + "\t\t" + frequency);

    // Populating alphaCounts array with the freq values
    alphaCounts[i] = frequency;
    i++;
    System.out.print("\n" + "alphaCounts: " + alphaCounts[i]);
}
```

Comment: What *something* is wrong?

Comment: @GurwinderSingh the bottom part where I am trying to assign the frequency values to the alphaCounts[] doesn't work for some reason...

Comment: What do you mean by `doesnt work`? you getting some errors? if so, what error? paste a stack.

Comment: You should tell us what you expect to happen, and what happens instead. Don't make us guess. "doesn't work" doesn't tell us anything. Also, this is not really optimal. Why make 26 passes on the string instead of just a single pass, finding the index of each letter, and incrementing the count at that index?`

Comment: @GurwinderSingh when I run the code, I get 0 for all the alphaCounts values. Instead for some of the letters I should get the frequency.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Comment: Remove `i++;` after `alphaCounts[i] = frequency;`.

Comment: Please realize that your "whole alphabet" only has 26 of the 109591 letters in the character set used by Java ([Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html)). And, an alphabet for a language is typically only a subset of the all the letter characters used in its writing system(s).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a piece of code to find the frequency of alphabets

```
String  input = "abcaaasdasdasd";
int freqarray[] = new int[26];
input = input.toUpperCase();
for(int i=0;i<input.length();i++)
{
    freqarray[input.charAt(i)-'A']++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few problems with your code. Your overall problem though probably comes from the fact that you increment `i` twice each loop; once in the for loop itself, once in the body near the end.

Another issue might be in how you define `alphabet`. Are you sure it contains the values of ascii characters 'a' through 'z'? And are you accounting for case? There is also no reason to use a separate array, you can go directly off the value of `j`, with appropriate adjustment.

Comment: Yes. But how can I add the values to the int array?

Comment: The way you add the values if correct. I suspect it's the rest of your code causing the counts to be 0.

Comment: When I run System.out.println(alphabet[i] + "\t\t" + frequency); I get all the alphabet letters a-z with the appropriate frequency or 0 if the letter doesn't appear in the string. However, when I try to insert those frequencies into the alphaCounts[] I insert 0.

Comment: Well your problem there is that you never store the values from `alphabet` into `alphaCounts`. Though as your code shown never modifies `alphabet` to begin with, I'm not really sure where you're getting those counts.

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert all characters in the input string to lower-case
2. Remove all non-alphabet characters
3. Create the frequency array, `new` also initializes all of its elements to zero.
4. Iterate over the transformed string and increase the counter for each occurring character. The expression `c - 'a'` transforms character `c` into an zero-based index for the array.
5. Print the frequency array

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
public class AlphabetCount {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String quote = "You can have data without information, but you cannot have information without data.";
        quote = quote.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z]", "");
        int[] frequencies = new int[26];
        for (char c : quote.toCharArray()) {
            frequencies[c - 'a'] = frequencies[c - 'a'] + 1;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(frequencies));
    }
}
```

```
$ java AlphabetCount.java
[10, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 4, 6, 0, 0, 0, 2, 7, 9, 0, 0, 2, 0, 10, 5, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0]
$
```

Answer (score -1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKNgG.png)I found a better solution after 3 days of struggling

quote = "You can have data without information, but you cannot have information without data."
quote = quote.lower()

alphabet = {'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0, 'd': 0, 'e': 0, 'f': 0, 'g': 0, 'h': 0, 'i': 0, 'j': 0, 'k': 0, 'l': 0, 'm': 0, 'n': 0, 'o': 0, 'p': 0, 'q': 0, 'r': 0, 's': 0, 't': 0, 'u': 0, 'v': 0, 'w': 0, 'x': 0, 'y': 0, 'z': 0}

for object, count in alphabet.items():
for let in quote:
let = let.split()
if object in let:
count += 1
print(object, count)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUrYq.png)